# Install GUI on Windows Server 2008 Core

Tags: windows-server-2008

We have a Server 2008 Core install whose requirements have changed - is it possible to install the GUI components in place, or is a reinstall necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A reinstall is necessary.  This is covered in [this Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951041):

> - You cannot upgrade from non-Server    Core installations of Windows Server
>     2008 to Server Core installations of Windows Server 2008.
> - You cannot    convert Server Core    installations of    Windows Server
>     2008 to non-Server    Core  installations of Windows Server
>       2008.

Answer (score 2):

Well its not a case of just adding the GUI, you have to upgrade from the core version to the full version of server 2008 (web, standard, etc.). Unfortunately there is not upgrade method to do this, you have to re-install the OS.