# upgrade from windows 2008 server CORE to full windows 2008 server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-core

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install GUI on Windows Server 2008 Core](https://serverfault.com/questions/4945/install-gui-on-windows-server-2008-core)

As I've seen there is not really a topic about this here... My question:
Is there any means to upgrade from windows 2008 server CORE to full windows 2008 server?

The server is used as Hyper-V Host machine.

On the internet mostly I find: "no you'll have to reinstall"
But maybe there's a workaround?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Massimo's right, but you'll find the official answer in [KB 951041](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951041):

> **Upgrade considerations for Server Core installations of Windows Server
>   2008**
>
> - You can use the Server Core    installation option only by performing a clean installation.
> - You    cannot upgrade from earlier versions    of Windows to Server Core 
>     installations of Windows Server 2008.
> - You cannot upgrade from non-Server    Core installations of Windows Server 2008 to Server Core installations of Windows Server 2008.
> - You cannot    convert Server Core installations of    Windows Server
>     2008 to non-Server    Core
>     installations of Windows Server 2008.
> - You can upgrade Server Core installations of Windows Server 2008
>     only to Windows Server Core R2 when it is released.

Comment: thx, ok, the answer to my question is a definite no then!